# Using Refit in Core/Android/IOS I encountered System.NotImplementedException error

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, refit

```
System.NotImplementedException: You've somehow included the PCL version of Refit in your app. You need to use the platform-specific version!
```

Currently using MVVMCross framework referenced the Core Project

I have tried this in multiple ways:

- Different versions of refit tested (all the same versions used).
- Tried to setup the DI within the Setup.cs (android platform), instead of the a PCL.
- I even tried to use a shared project instead of a PCL. Only xamarin android had refit installed - no logical way a PCL could break it,
  but still gave the same error..
- I checked the actual Refit for Android `\app\packages\refit.2.4.1\lib\MonoAndroid\Refit.dll`
- I checked the actual Refit for IOS `\app\packages\refit.2.4.1\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Refit.dll`

Have I missed something?