# Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Could not install package 'Refit 4.0.1'

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, refit

Installing Refit in Xamarin MvvmCross Profile 111 .NetPortable 4.5

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error Could not install package 'Refit 4.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.    0
```

Issued in [Refit Issue #376](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit/issues/376)

The [docs](http://paulcbetts.github.io/refit/) did say

> Refit currently supports the following platforms and any .NET Standard
>   1.4 target:
>
> - UWP
> - Xamarin.Android
> - Xamarin.Mac
> - Xamarin.iOS
> - Desktop
> - .NET 4.5
> - .NET Core

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing Refit 4 into a PCL. Refit is a NET Standard 1.4 library which cannot be consumed by *any* PCL profile.

Upgrade your PCL to NET Standard (minimum 1.4) or downgrade Refit to a previous version which was not NET Standard.

Comment: actually I used 2.4.1 but Im having issue with [System.NotImplementedException: You've somehow included the PCL version of Refit in your app. You need to use the platform-specific version!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46453218/3974048)

Comment: I also tried platform specific refit, but I referenced the core which also has refit installed, so does this mean that the referenced refit is used in each platform? Correct me if im wrong please

Comment: That is a different problem from what you have asked in the opening post.

Comment: Yes anyway thanks for the answer. I do think also that I need to upgrade my PCL to Net Standard. Is there any side effects upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

I built the .Net Core app using Angular CLI, I stopped the dotnet watch run and re-executed the scaffolding (which was causing this build error) and it worked fine with no error